# Starting an admin shell then executing multiple commands

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script and a bat file that launches it. I want the bat file to open powershell, then have powershell start another shell with elevated privileges, then run two commands. First command is change directory, second command is start a powershell script.

So far I have this:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-NoExit -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass cd %~dp0 .\App\Deploy-Application.ps1}'"
```

This is the section I'm having problems with:

```
cd %~dp0 .\App\Deploy-Application.ps1
```

I want to run these two commands but I'm not sure how. It runs a single command. I tried adding a semicolon between the commands but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Made a quick test and this is what i got working:

Test.bat

```
cd %~dp0
powershell -NoProfile -Command ".\test.ps1"
```

Test.ps1

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
    $arguments = "-noprofile & '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
    Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
    Break
}

Write-Host "Rawr"

Pause
```

If i run the batch file, it opens the powershell script that then checks if the current window is being run as an administrator and if not, reopens the script as an administrator.

After which it displays Rawr on my screen.

In your case instead of the Write-Host you could put

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
    $arguments = "-noprofile & '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
    Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
    Break
}

cd <Your directory to change to here>
<run command here>

Pause
```

Comment: This looks much nicer than my solution. Going to try it out tomorrow.